Unable to load external script for google_sign_in_web pub.dev in Flutter Chrome Extension
I am building a chrome extension using flutter web. My extension has a sign in with google button. it works on a deployed website. But as a chrome extension it fails as I am not able to load externals scripts in manifest v3. It is because this url is being blocked https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client.
I have tried downloading the contents of https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client to my local folder as "google_sso.js" and importing it via  tag in my index.html. Do I need to modify code within the pub.dev SDK to get this to work? I tried all options with loosening security to allow external scripts, but it's not working.
I attached a picture of some workaround I am attempting. I'll appreciate any guidance you can give me.
VScode screenshot of modified SDK
I import it like this inside my index.html
  <script src="google_sso.js" defer></script>

This is the code I am thinking of modifying to make this work. Not sure. Here's what i tried
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:js_interop';

import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;

import 'js_interop/load_callback.dart';
import 'js_interop/package_web_tweaks.dart';

// The URL from which the script should be downloaded.
const String _url = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';

// The default TrustedPolicy name that will be used to inject the script.
const String _defaultTrustedPolicyName = 'gis-dart';

Future<void> loadWebSdk({
  web.HTMLElement? target,
  String trustedTypePolicyName = _defaultTrustedPolicyName,
}) {
  final Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
  onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => completer.complete();

  // Try loading the script from the URL first
  final web.HTMLScriptElement script = web.document.createElement('script') as web.HTMLScriptElement
    ..async = true
    ..defer = true
    ..src = _url;

  // Fallback to loading the local google_sso.js file if the URL fails or throws a CSP error
  script.onError.listen((event) {
    web.console.warn('Failed to load script from URL. Falling back to local file.'.toJS);
    script.src = 'google_sso.js';
  });

  (target ?? web.document.head!).appendChild(script);
  return completer.future;
}

